# A system of linear PDEs in cylindrical coordinates.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following system of PDEs:

$$\partial_r b_2 - \partial_{\theta}b_1 = 0, \\
\partial_{\theta} b_3 - \partial_{z}b_2 = 0, \\
~~~~~~~\partial_rb_3 - \partial_{z}b_1 = \xi(r, z), $$

where $\xi(r, z)$ is a given function depending only on $(r, z)$ and $b_1, b_2, b_3$ are unknown functions of $(r, \theta, z)$. This system is written in cylindrical coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Fix, once and for all, a function $\xi(r, z)$ such that the following holds:

**Assumption: The above system has a unique solution ($b_1$, $b_2$, $b_3$)**.

**Question**: For this solution, can we claim that $b_2 = 0$?

**My thoughts on this**: I wanna say that, knowing a solution exists, one could in particular solve the third equation for $b_1, b_3$ depending on $r$ and $z$ alone. Then, since they don't depend on $\theta$, one could take $b_2 = 0$ and find **a** solution. Since it's unique, that has to be **the** solution. Is this reasoning correct?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by "unique solution"? It seems that, if $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ is a solution, then for every $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ also $(b_1+\alpha_1, b_2+\alpha_2, b_3+\alpha_3)$ solves the system.

Answer (score 1):

First, from the third equation it follows that we can write $b_1(r,\theta,z) = \beta_1(r,z) + z f(\theta)$ and $b_3(r,\theta,z) = \beta_3(r,z) + r f(\theta)$, with $\frac{\partial \beta_3}{\partial r} - \frac{\partial \beta_1}{\partial z} = \xi(r,z)$. From the first equation, we see that
\begin{equation}
b_2(r,\theta,z) = r z f'(\theta) + g(r), \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and from the second equation, we see that
\begin{equation}
b_2(r,\theta,z) = z r f'(\theta) + h(z). \tag{2}
\end{equation}
Comparing $(1)$ and $(2)$, it's clear that $g(r)$ and $h(z)$ must be zero. However, it's also clear that any function $b_2$ of the form $b_2(r,\theta,z) = r z f'(\theta)$ obeys the set of partial differential equations. To conclude: the system does **not** force $b_2$ to be zero. Moreover, as you see, it does **not** follow that $b_1$ and $b_3$ are independent of $\theta$.

Generally speaking, you have a system of the form
\begin{equation}
 \nabla \times \mathbf{b} = \mathbf{f}. \tag{3}
\end{equation}
Because the divergence of the curl vanishes, taking the divergence on both sides of $(3)$ yields
\begin{equation}
 0 = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{f} = \frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, we can conclude that $(3)$ has a solution only if $\frac{\partial \xi}{\partial z} = 0$.

Any remarks on the uniqueness of a solution of $(3)$ depend on boundary conditions. If you don't specify boundary conditions, any solution to $(3)$ is not unique. In this particular case, there is an additional source of non-uniqueness from the equation itself: you can add any gradient of a function to $\mathbf{b}$, i.e. replace $\mathbf{b} \to \mathbf{b} + \nabla \phi$, and it will still obey $(3)$. For more information, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_potential#Nonuniqueness).

Comment: One comment is that if you want to extend these solutions to $r = 0$, they have to at least vanish there, which would imply $f(\theta) = 0$. On the other hand, I don't see why $b_1$ and $b_3$ have to have the form you wrote in your first sentence.

Comment: If one of the boundary conditions is that $\mathbf{b}(0,\theta,z) = 0$, then it indeed follows that $f(\theta) = 0$ from the expression for $b_1$. To answer your second question: if the difference between $\partial_r b_3$ and $\partial_z b_1$ is independent of $\theta$, that means that we can write $\partial_r b_3 = A(r,z) + C(r,z,\theta)$ and $\partial_z b_1 = B(r,z) + C(r,z,\theta)$, i.e. we can add an arbitrary function $C(r,\theta,z)$ to both $\partial_r b_3$ and $\partial_z b_1$, because this does not change the fact that their difference is $\theta$-independent. Here I just took...

Comment: ... $C(r,\theta,z) = f(\theta)$ to make this point more clear. For general $C(r,\theta,z)$ you can follow the same procedure.